# R sub extract everything before last occurence of a character

Tags: r

I have the following vector c:

```
ABC-XXX
DEF-4-YYY
```

I want to extract everything before the last occurence of '-', meaning that I would keep this

```
ABC
DEF-4
```

I've tried the following:

```
sub([-].*, '', "DEF-4-YYY")
```

But this replaces everything after the first '-', while it should look for the last '-'. Output of the above command is:

```
"DEF"
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can do with `sub` by matching a `-` followed by zero or more characters that are not a `-` till the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blank (`''`)

```
sub('-[^-]*$', '', v1)
#[1] "ABC"   "DEF-4"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('ABC-XXX', 'DEF-4-YYY')
```

Answer (score 4):

if you prefer you can use stringr package

```
library(stringr)
matches=str_locate_all(c,"-")
chars=sapply(matches,function(x) x[nrow(x),])[1,]
str_sub(c,1,chars-1)
```